# UserControl DependencyProperty propertyChangedCallback not called

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

So I have an ItemsControl set in my xaml as such:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <local:ToggleButton Command="{Binding DataContext.ItemSelectedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type WrapPanel}}}" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" 
                                    Text="{Binding DataContext.ItemEnum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" 
                                    IsActive="{Binding DataContext.Selected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    Width="96" 
                                    Height="88" 
                                    Margin="5" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I  have the 4 dependency properties `Command`, `CommandParameter`, `Text`, and `IsActive`.
The first 3 dependency properties work correctly, the text is set, and the command callback works with the parameter.

The `IsActive` property however does NOT work.
The Items property in the main viewmodel is defined as:

```
List<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
```

The ItemViewModel is defined as:

```
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ItemViewModel()
    {
        this.Selected = true;
    }

    private bool? _selected;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ItemEnum ItemEnum { get; set; }

    public bool? Selected
    {
        get { return this._selected; }

        set
        {
            this._selected = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Selected));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

the dependency property for the `IsActive` property in the ToggleButton.xaml.cs file looks like:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActiveProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsActive), typeof(bool?), typeof(ToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(null, IsActiveSetCallback));

private static void IsActiveSetCallback(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (ToggleButton)obj;

    button.IsActive = (bool)(e.NewValue ?? e.OldValue);0xa5, 0xa5));
}
```

My command callback in the main view model looks like this:

```
this.ItemSelectedCommand = 
      new DelegateCommand(
          itemVm =>
          {
               bool? setTo = !((ItemViewModel) itemVm).Selected;
               this.Items.ForEach(i => i.Selected = false);
               ((ItemViewModel) itemVm).Selected = setTo;
          });
```

Again, the other dependency properties (defined basically identically to `IsActiveProperty`) work correctly, so when I click the item, the above command gets called (verified by breakpoint), the item's Selected flag gets toggled properly, but the IsActiveSetCallback never gets hit.  I can't see what I'm doing wrong, but clearly it's something.

Does anyone see something that I don't?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending too much time trying to solve this, of course I manage to solve it myself within half an hour of posting this question..

I pulled this from the Microsoft DependencyProperty docs, specifically the section about 'Dependency Property Setting Precedence List':

> **Local value**. A local value might be set through the convenience of the "wrapper" property, which also equates to setting as an attribute or property element in XAML, or by a call to the SetValue API using a property of a specific instance. If you set a local value by using a binding or a resource, these each act in the precedence as if a direct value was set.

So, I was setting `this.Active` in two places in the ToggleButton.xaml.cs, once in the constructor as a default value, and once in the IsActiveSetCallback .. turns out by doing that, I was overriding the binding, and neither of those calls were necessary anyways. So simple!